# removeClass from parent selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element where I add an class to but when the array is empty than remove that certain class but it is not working.

```
if(arr.length <= 0){
  console.log('arr.length <= 0', $(titleContains).parents('.pass-item').removeClass('passFrame'))
  titleContains.parents('.pass-item').removeClass('passFrame');
  titleContains.parents('.passFrame').find('.image img').attr('src', calendarOriginalImgSrc);
}
```

the console log above shows me this result:

```
arr.length <= 0  init [li.pass-item, prevObject: init(1), context: document]
                 0: li.pass-item.passFrame
                 context: document
                 length: 1
                 prevObject: init [div.title, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: ".pass-item .title:contains(10 dagen binnen 1 maand)"]
```

I allready tried selecting `[0]` index like this:

```
  titleContains.parents('.pass-item')[0].removeClass('passFrame');
```

But this is not working and throws me an error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan throws me this error: `b.parents(...).get(...).removeClass is not a function`

Comment: `titleContains.parents('.pass-item').get(0).removeClass('passFrame')`

Comment: Apologies, my mistake - you need `eq()`, not `get()`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan also tried that but that is not removing the class

Comment: It does: http://jsfiddle.net/pwy4ctug/